# The attempt to bind "/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" in the workspace failed as this URI is malformed CRA

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, string-interpolation

I got the following errors when trying to run an app created using CRA

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.

The attempt to bind "/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" in the workspace failed as this URI is malformed.

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
```

At first, I thought it was related to the use of custom env variables.

```
REACT_APP_DUMMY_ENV=thisisdummyenv
REACT_APP_FOO=bar
```

However, after making sure I was following the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/), I decided to log the env variables during build time.

Since the project uses CRA, I added the following line to `node_modules/react-scripts/config/env.js` at line 103. (`react-scripts@4.0.3`)

```js
console.log({ env: process.env, raw});
```

So, I noticed that the env variables are being recognized, but not interpolated in the generated HTML file as shown below.

[image: screenshot of the error]

Answer (score 0):

After spending so many hours trying to solve this issue, I noticed that the project path had encoded whitespaces (`%20`)

```
/home/user/path/to/my%20cloned%20repo
```

So, you only need to get them removed

```
/home/user/path/to/my_cloned_repo
```

And it should work!

Comment: Did you need to change anything in your code? or was simply renaming your project folder?